# Is there a way to set TCP options using the sockets API?

Tags: tcp, sockets

I am relatively new to socket programming so this may sound like a very lame question.
I have to use authenticated TCP(MD5 as a TCP option to start with) as a transport for some application. I was wondering if this could be done using the sockets API or there is some other form of an existing TCP APIs that I could use to do the same. I would appreciate if I could get some help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your question. You can certainly set socket options on a socket using the [setsockopt](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=setsockopt) function, but by the sound of the rest of your question, this isn't quite what you mean. I've never heard of any transport protocol called *Authenticated TCP* and google throws up nothing useful. Is it a standard; is there an RFC?

If you're just wanting a secure, authenticated TCP transport layer, then you should look in to Secure Sockets Layer, or **SSL** for short, or its replacement, Transport Layer Security, or [TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) for short. There will almost certainly be an implementation for whatever language you're using (you haven't specified).

- For C/C++, there's: [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/)
- For .Net, there's: [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx)
- For Java, there's the [Secure Socket Extensions](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html)

Also, what do you mean by MD5 for authentication? MD5 is a hashing algorithm, however it's not collision resistant enough for use in communication that requires secure signatures.

**Edit** aha! You're talking about TCP options, I understand now. I haven't seen any implementations of that particular TCP option built in to any of the socket APIs, so you may be out of luck here. It depends on the implementation you use, but it might be especially rare given that this is a fairly obscure TCP option designed for enhancing the border gateway protocol, not something you would usually have use for outside of routing software. In case it is supported, you would set it something like this:

```
BOOL optVal = TRUE;
int optLen = sizeof(BOOL);

if (setsockopt(
      socket,
      IPPROTO_TCP,
      TCP_WHATEVER,
      optVal,
      optLen) != SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("Success\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks IRBMe! 
I am referring to RFC 2385. To make a long story short and based on the nature of the application, we have to use TCP with MD5 option as the transport (C implementation). I see sockets API as one possible option to setup this kind of a transport. I was wondering if there exist some other API set that could do the same thing but at the same time simplify the implementation a bit. 
thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Here is the usage for Linux: http://criticalindirection.com/2015/05/12/tcp_md5sig/

sockopt struct:

```
struct tcp_md5sig {
    struct  __kernel_sockaddr_storage tcpm_addr;
    __u16   __tcpm_pad1;
    __u16   tcpm_keylen;
    __u32   __tcpm_pad2;
    __u8    tcpm_key[TCP_MD5SIG_MAXKEYLEN];
};
```

The Linux man page has no reference even though the functionality is present in kernel and libc.

From the link:

> The socket option TCP_MD5SIG saves a mapping of the pre-shared MD5 key
>   against the corresponding peer endpoint. It is mandatory to bind the
>   client to a particular IP and port known to the server. The
>   setsockopt() must be called on the listen socket of the server and the
>   connection socket of the client, before the connect() gets called from
>   client.

It also has full client-server example. Below is a snippet:

```
//Sockets Layer Call: bind()
memset((char *) &cl_addr, 0, sizeof(cl_addr));
cl_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
if(inet_pton(AF_INET6, c6ip, &cl_addr.sin6_addr) <= 0)
    error("ERROR on inet_pton");
cl_addr.sin6_port = htons(atoi(cport));

if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cl_addr, sizeof(cl_addr)) < 0)
    error("ERROR on binding");


memset((char *) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
if(inet_pton(AF_INET6, s6ip, &serv_addr.sin6_addr) <= 0)
    error("ERROR on inet_pton");
serv_addr.sin6_port = htons(atoi(sport));


memcpy(&md5.tcpm_addr, &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
strcpy(md5.tcpm_key, key);
md5.tcpm_keylen = strlen(key);

if ((r = setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_MD5SIG, &md5, sizeof(md5))) < 0)
    error("listen setsockopt TCP_MD5SIG");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the TCP-MD5 option described by [RFC 2385](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2385.txt), a few systems such as FreeBSD support a boolean TCP_MD5SIG option to enable this.  It is enabled on a socket as follows:

```
int opt = 1;
setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_MD5SIG, &opt, sizeof(opt));
```

See [`tcp(4)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tcp&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+11-current&arch=default&format=html) for further details.

Linux has a different version of this that uses a struct parameter; the other answers here have some additional details.

Comment: Well this wrong. 'opt' is not an int in this sockopt. It is struct tcpm_addr.

Comment: @user31986: oh thanks, on FreeBSD it is a boolean option, but apparently it uses a struct on Linux.  I've updated the answer to clarify this.

Comment: This option cannot be just boolean on any platform, because you should provide a key as well.

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler: On FreeBSD the key is set separately.  See the `TCP_MD5SIG` entry in [`tcp(4)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tcp&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+11-current&arch=default&format=html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented a TCP-MD5 connection class in Ruby, and thought this code snippet might save anyone else the effort (at least anyone who is doing it on Linux, where the facility is undocumented).  This was just from looking at headers and experimenting; hopefully the Ruby isn't too scary for people writing in other languages.

```
class TCPMD5Socket < Socket
  IPPROTO_TCP =  6 # linux/in.h
  TCP_MD5SIG  = 14 # linux/tcp.h
  TCP_MD5SIG_MAXKEYLEN = 80 # linux/tcp.h

  # Works exactly the same as TCPSocket.open except you can supply a password
  # to pass to the kernel for MD5 authhentication.
  #
  def initialize(host, port, password)
    raise ArgumentError.new("Password is too long") if 
      password.length > TCP_MD5SIG_MAXKEYLEN

    family = Socket.const_get(IPAddr.new(host).ipv4? ? "AF_INET" : "AF_INET6")
    super(family, Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0)      
    # struct tcp_md5sig {
    #   struct __kernel_sockaddr_storage tcpm_addr; /* address associated */
    #   __u16   __tcpm_pad1;                /* zero */
    #   __u16   tcpm_keylen;                /* key length */
    #   __u32   __tcpm_pad2;                /* zero */
    #   __u8    tcpm_key[TCP_MD5SIG_MAXKEYLEN];     /* key (binary) */
    # };
    tcp_md5sig_buffer = [
      Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(port, host), 0, password.length, 0, password
    ].pack("a128SSLa#{TCP_MD5SIG_MAXKEYLEN}")    
    setsockopt(IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_MD5SIG, tcp_md5sig_buffer)
    connect(Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(port, host))
  end
end
```

This won't work on anything but Linux 2.6.20 onwards, but at least if you're on FreeBSD instead, it's described in a [man page](http://fuse4bsd.creo.hu/localcgi/man-cgi.cgi?tcp+4).